# How to get a list from firebase to ion-list

Tags: ionic3

Here is the code i am using but i am getting the firebase id with the data in an array

```
firebase.database().ref("messages").child("messages").on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
  var datas = child.val();
  console.log(datas);
  return false; 

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *ngFor="let item of Arrayitems" to iterate your array

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of Arrayitems">
    <ion-item>{{ item.name }}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```